# read the http links from a file and append it to a list

Tags: file, http, python-2.7

I am still a beginner.I have a 'link.txt' file with several links  in it..
for example:

```
http://google.com
http://google.com
http://google.com
http://google.com
http://google.com
```

How do I read  them by using python because when I use this snippet code I get all the links as single line of text. Here is the code.

```
file = open('path')
a = file.read()
for all in a:
    if 'http:' in all:
        print a
```

Expected output:

```
list = ['http://google.com','http://google.com','http://google.com','http://google.com']
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("filename_here") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
print content
```

Comment: to strip newlines, you could: `lines = f.read().splitlines()`